# how to set up an ETH sweeper bot or scavenger on a private key

Tags: wallets, private-key, smart-contract-wallets, wallet-transfer

So I have been studying wallet sweeper bot or scavenger hunt which somehow linked to the private key and as soon you send some Eth to that wallet address it sends to another wallet address of the attacker. SO far I know this and completely understand it.
Now I have the following two questions?

1- How to set up this bot sweeper on/in a private key or how to link it with the private key?
2- If the private key has already been set by the wallet sweeper bot then can you set it again on the same key?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Anyone can create a transaction and sign with a private key. The bots are just listening for balance changes and creating a transaction to transfer the funds to another wallet. Existing bots are much more advanced they listen for new transactions before they are mined in the pending pool, and calculate fees to maximize the probability of being mined quickly.